# Is equality a necessary condition for anti-symmetric relation

Tags: relations

There are two questions

> S is the set of all people and R is the relation on set S such that $(a, b) \in R$, where $a$ and $b$ are people if $a$ is taller than $b$

According to the solution, this relation is anti-symmetric, which makes sense at first look. Clearly if $a$ is taller than $b$, then $b$ cannot be taller than $a$. Moving on to the second question;

> S is the set of all people and R is the relation on set S such that $(a, b) \in R$, where $a$ and $b$ are people if $a$ is not taller than $b$

Now according to the solution, this is not anti-symmetric, since while it is true that if $a$ is not taller than $b$, then $b$ is not taller than $a$, unless $a$ and $b$ are of the same height, but that does not be $a = b$ since they are two distinct people, hence the equality does not hold.

The equality part is confusing me. If we look at the first question, and the definition of anti-symmetry

> the relation R is antisymmetric if $aRb$ and $bRa$ implies $a = b$.

and clearly, $a$ cannot be taller than $a$, so why is the first question anti-symmetric while the second one is declared anti-symmetric based on the same equality technicality?

For more clarification, let $aRb$ in the first question. Then $b \not R a$ unless $a = b$ according to the very definition of anti-symmetry. But it is not true that $a R a$, so how can we declare it to be anti-symmetric?

Comment: The first relation never fulfills the antecedent, so the implication is always true.

Comment: An equivalent definition of antisymmetry is: if $a\ne b$, then we can’t have both $aRb$ and $bRa$. Perhaps this is easier to consider for you?

Comment: @Damian ok that makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

Logically, the comments by [Damian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557973/is-equality-a-necessary-condition-for-anti-symmetric-relation#comment9587567_4557973) and [Milten](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4557973/is-equality-a-necessary-condition-for-anti-symmetric-relation#comment9587593_4557973) are good explanations. $a\Rightarrow b$ is true if $a$ is always false, and conversely, $\neg b \Rightarrow \neg a$ is also true if $a$ is always false. Grasping this intuitively does require a little bit of brain gymnastics at first though.

It might be a little easier to get your head around it if we phrase things less mathematically precise and more in line with how we usually think about relations: *an operator with something on either side of it*. Instead of

> the relation $R$ is antisymmetric if $aRb$ and $bRa$ implies $a=b$.

let's say

> the relation is antisymmetric if you can never swap the two sides unless they're identical

or even more obviously

> the relation is antisymmetric if you can never swap the two sides, **possibly** unless they're identical

Antisymmetry poses no requirement on $aRa$ -- it might be true, it might be false. **If** it is true, then yes, you can of course swap the two sides (because it doesn't really change anything).

But that's the **only** case where you would ever be allowed to do it. If the two sides aren't the same, no swapping.